# Вывод данных из формы в таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных, из неё делал вывод в таблицы по видеоурокам. 
Где-то сделал ощибку, но уже второй день не могу понять где.
Сами таблицы сделаны на основе шаблона админки SRTdash.
Это как я получаю данные из бд:

```
    <?php
    //Параметры подключения в БД
    $host = "localhost"; //имя хоста
    $database = "test1"; //имя базы
    $user = "root"; //пользователь
    $password = ""; //пароль
    $dbtable = "Users"; //таблица

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

    function get_users() {
        global $link;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $users;
    }

?>
```

В файле index.php вызываю этот скрипт следующим образом:

```
<?php
    require_once 'functions.php';
    ?>
```

Затем сами таблицы и как я в них вставляю данные из бд.

```
<?php
            $post = get_users();
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($post as $users): ?>
            <div class="main-content-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- table primary start -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 class="header-title">Анкета №<?=$post['id']?> (<?=$post['order_date']?> <?=$post['order_time']?>)</h4>
                              <h6>Позвонить Менеджеру: <?=$post['surname']?> <?=$post['name']?> <?=$post['second_name']?> <?=$post['phone']?></h6>
                              <div class="single-table">
                                  <div class="table-responsive">
                                      <table class="table text-center">
                                          <thead class="text-uppercase bg-primary">
                                              <tr class="text-white">
                                                  <th scope="col">Номер</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">ФИО</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Дата рождения</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Место рождения</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Гражданство</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Срок</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">Доставка</th>
                                                  <th scope="col">На доставку</th>
                                              </tr>
                                          </thead>


 <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                              <th scope="row"><?=$post['phone']?></th>
                                              <td><?=$post['surname']?> <?=$post['name']?> <?=$post['second_name']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['birth_date']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['birth_place']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['citizenship']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['term']?></td>
                                              <td><div class="form-group">
                                                  <select class="form-control">
                                                      <option>Автово</option>
                                                      <option>Ломоносовская</option>
                                                      <option>Дыбенко</option>
                                                  </select>
                                              </div></td>
                                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success mb-3">Отправить</button></td>

                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>

                                      <thead class="text-uppercase bg-primary">
                                          <tr class="text-white">
                                              <th scope="col">Документ</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Номер документа</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Дата выдачи</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Кем выдан</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Адрес регистрации</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Комментарий</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Время доставки</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Отказ</th>
                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                              <th scope="row"><?=$post['doc']?></th>
                                              <td><?=$post['doc_id']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['doc_date']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['doc_publish']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['adress_register']?></td>
                                              <td><?=$post['comment']?></td>
                                              <td><div class="form-group">
                                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="С 10 до 12" id="example-text-input">
                                              </div></td>
                                              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger mb-3">Отказ</button></td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

В итоге, если я делаю так:

```
$users = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

У меня заполняется вся страница копиями таблицы с id=1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я делаю как в примере видеоурока:

```
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Тогда я получаю нужно количество таблиц (равное количеству id), но с пустыми данными.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните, пожалуйста, где я ошибся и как это исправить.

Comment: <?php foreach ($post as **$users**): ?>. К какой переменной теперь надо обращаться, чтобы получить данные одного юзера? А ты к какой обращаешься? Вопрос можно удалять

Comment: @Ипатьев Поясните, пожалуйста, что именно я не так сделал?

Comment: @web2k17 замените переменную. например `$post['id']` на `$users['id']`